# What determines the speed of charging of a battery?

Tags: batteries

Recently we have seen the surge of superfast mobile phone charging. Just an example: http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-30708945

What underlying physical principle determines the speed of charging of a battery?

Comment: This question really belongs into chemistry. The only physically relevant problems would be charge conservation, which requires very high charging currents and thermodynamics losses, which lead to very high heat generation in the device. A fast charging battery that ends up at 150 degrees C is useless for consumer applications and so is a battery that would require water cooling while it is being charged.

Comment: I thought chemistry is just applied physics ;)

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44547/what-determines-the-speed-of-charging-of-a-battery

Comment: Yes, just like surgery is applied medicine, which is applied biology, which is applied chemistry, which is applied chemistry, which is applied physics. I guess next time you need to have an appendectomy, I will come by your house and we'll do it on the kitchen table. According to your statement I should be fully qualified. :-)